# Is there a way to test psychological theories online?

Tags: experimental-psychology

There are some online simulations in physics and chemistry, nearly all fields of science can be simulated online. I wonder if psychology can be "simulated" too, and I wonder if there is something already being used to do that.

Comment: Simulating theories is not the same as testing them.  If you are asking about simulations, then this question may be a duplicate of [Easy-to-use simulations of human behavior](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23213/7001) or [Where can I find online interactive versions of classic experiments in psychology for the purposes of teaching?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10319/7001).  If you are asking about testing, then try [searching](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/search?q=online+platforms) this forum for lots of examples.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg thanks, I meant like testing with real people

Comment: You're welcome.  Closing as [answered in comments](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2163/7001).